# Update records based on other records in the same table

Tags: sqlite

I have a table (Pump_Table) with pump flow (Pump_Flow), pump station names (Name) and sub name (Sub_Name) information, as presented in the table extract below:

[image]

I would like to transfer the pump_flow value from sub_name Pump 1 to the pump_flow field for sub_name; Pump 2, Pump 3,... Pump n, of a pump station having the same name.

The script I've created looks like this:

```
    Update [Pump_Table]
    SET [Pump_Flow] = (
                      SELECT [Pump_Flow]
                      FROM [Pump_Table]
                      WHERE [Name] = [Name]
                      AND [Sub_Name] = "Pump 1"
                      )
    WHERE [Name] = [Name]
    AND [Sub_Name] != "Pump 1"
    ;
```

It keeps on returning the value from the pump_flow field of the first record in the table that has 'Pump 1' in the sub_name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter `Name = Name` always matches.

To refer to a value in another table, you must use the table name.
If that other table is an instance of the same table, you must rename one table:

```
Update Pump_Table
SET Pump_Flow = (SELECT Pump_Flow
                 FROM Pump_Table AS P1
                 WHERE P1.Name = Pump_Flow.Name
                   AND Sub_Name = 'Pump 1')
WHERE Sub_Name != 'Pump 1';
```